# wp_get_object_terms returns empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I have taxonomy called mh_menu.
I want to get terms for object, and for it I'm using wp_get_object_terms.
When I do

```
wp_get_object_terms(639, 'mh_menu', array('fields' => 'all', 
'orderby' => 'none'));
```

I get result with terms array

```
WP_Term Object                                                                                                        
(                                                                                               
[term_id] => 118
[name] => new cat
[slug] => new-cat
[term_group] => 0
[term_taxonomy_id] => 118
[taxonomy] => mh_menu
[description] => 
[parent] => 0
[count] => 2
[filter] => raw
)
```

and etc

but When I do

```
wp_get_object_terms(639, 'mh_menu', array('fields' => 'tt_ids', 
'orderby' => 'none'));
```

I get empty array

```
Array
(
)
```

And the most interesting thing that I have two wordpress sites (all is up to date) and in first site it's working but in the second site it's returning empty array.

Comment: It seems like there is no field tt_ids. What is tt_ids?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms

tt_ids : term's taxonomy's ids will be returned

Comment: With same code it is having the different results? wordpress version and everything is same ?

Comment: wordpress versions is the same, they are copy websites, so all plugins and anything is the same.

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, the problem was from hierarchy. I've deleted whole term, and recreated, so the information for hierarchy was right, and all worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try my code and let me know what you are getting in the count in the printed array.

```
wp_get_object_terms(639, 'mh_menu', array('fields' => 'tt_ids', 'orderby' => 'none','hide_empty' => false));
```

If you found 0 than please add the post to respective category and revert your code back as this is the simple default wordpress behavior.

If your category is not map to the post wordpress default not allowing you to display that category. If you still wish to show that category than you need to pass the `hide_empty` as a `false` in your argument.